# Question about publishing to Appstore/Android Market

Tags: iphone, android, app-store, google-play

I am developing an enterprise application for Android and iPhone platforms.

The question is if you have any way to publish on the AppStore and Android Market and make the application available only to users of this company and not available to anyone outside the company?

There are approximately 300 people who would use the App.

Thanks

Andre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android, it's pretty easy:

You can distribute the .apk file (the application package) without having to use the market at all.  You can either post it on a web server, or otherwise send it to them via email.

Bonus: If you send it to the GMAIL account they use on their phone, the can install the apk file attachment directly.

As far as limiting distribution in the Android market, you really can't prevent people from discovering and downloading your application.  Your best bet is to keep distribution local to your company using a private web server.

For iOS, check out the enterprise license.

Answer (score 2):

I think an authentication process would be helpful in that case. However in iOS's case I would recommend to get an [enterprise](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/) license, for your requirements.